# Logging in Flex web application

Tags: java, apache-flex, logging, actionscript

I am creating Flex web application with java. and deployed on tomcat server.
I have created logging in java using log4j. But not able to understand how to start logging in flex web application. 
I have searched lot but not find any stepwise solution for this problem. 
Here I am not using blazeDS.
Please suggest how to create log file for flex and stored to server.

Comment: Flex runs completely on client side, you need to do communication between flex app and server side and put your logs there.

Answer (score 0):

whether you want to create client-side logging or server-side logging.
In case of client-side Logging you can either configure your application to create log file or to write directly to log file
configure server-side logging in the logging section of the config file-->services-config.xml

Comment: Log file is create as name flashlog.txt, but is showing log of other application. for eg. when I opened msn.com this file also appending the logs of msn.com.
Is any way to prevant it? so I can see only my application log to logger file.